# Unable to get the JSON response from server into the store after form submission in Extjs

Tags: php, json, extjs

I have a login form which submits the Username, Password values to the server on submit button click.

```
var form = this.up('form').getForm();
    if (form.isValid()) {
        form.submit({
            url: '', //this is the url where the form gets submitted
            success: function(form, action) {
               Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
            },
            failure: function(form, action) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

But after the submit button click the Web page (Web App) is getting redirected to the URL which I have provided for form submission showing the response from the server.

I need to store the JSON response from the server into store without getting redirected and stay on same page.

Please help me in solving this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set standardSubmit property of form to false:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    standardSubmit: false,
    ...
```